# I need help for writing a Stored Procedures in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I’m a newbie in Stored Procedures in SQL Server 2005. Let’s say we have a table with these columns: `Id (GUID)`, `UserId (string)`, `DayOfYear (int)`, `Score (int)`.

I need a SP with one input (`inputDayOfYear`) which copy last day (inputDayOfYear=10 => last day DayOfYear=9) data with new `Id` but old `UserId` and `Score`, and current `DayOfYear` (th input parameter) to new rows.

- One important thing is to ignore
  those records that have data of
  `DayOfYear` same as `inputDayOfYear`.
- Performance is also very important
  here; there are may be over 1000 rows
  for each `DayOfYear`.
- Return value is
  not necessary but number of new rows
  would be fine.

---

I’ll be appreciated if you introduce me to some good resources to learn SP, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your request correctly this should help you

```
    DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        UserID INT,
        [DayOfYear] INT,
        Score INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table (ID,UserID,DayOfYear,Score) SELECT NEWID(), 1, 1, 10
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,UserID,DayOfYear,Score) SELECT NEWID(), 2, 1, 100
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,UserID,DayOfYear,Score) SELECT NEWID(), 2, 2, 1000
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,UserID,DayOfYear,Score) SELECT NEWID(), 1, 3, 10

DECLARE @inputDayOfYear INT
SELECT @inputDayOfYear = 3

/* THIS GOES INTO SP*/
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,UserID,DayOfYear,Score)
SELECT  NEWID(),
        UserID,
        @inputDayOfYear,
        Score 
FROM    @Table
WHERE   [DayOfYear] = @inputDayOfYear - 1
AND     UserID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM @Table WHERE [DayOfYear] = @inputDayOfYear)
/* THIS GOES INTO SP*/

SELECT * FROM @Table

/* SP TO CREATE */
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertValues(@inputDayOfYear AS INT)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Table (ID,UserID,DayOfYear,Score)
    SELECT  NEWID(),
            UserID,
            @inputDayOfYear,
            Score 
    FROM    @Table
    WHERE   [DayOfYear] = @inputDayOfYear - 1
AND     UserID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM @Table WHERE [DayOfYear] = @inputDayOfYear)
END
/* SP TO CREATE */
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, but I think I forgot to tell you that UserId is unique per DayOfYear.
In you SP what will happen if there was a DayOfYear=3 for UserId=1?!

Comment: OK, i fixed that specification for you. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

This MSDN page has been the most useful resource I have found for learning and exploring T-SQL and stored procedures.

[MSDN T-SQL Reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa299742(SQL.80).aspx)